# AndroidMy 6.0 targetSdkVersion 23 open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, android-studio

I got a error, W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Code has :

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

AndroidManifest.xml has :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

build.gradle has:

```
targetSdkVersion is 23
```

Comment: Read [Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Refer this link you may get the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/4069985

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not ask permission to do these actions, you have to ask the users to grant your app these permissions. 
See this related post: [Storage permission error in Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is security permission needed from Lollipop

```
public static boolean checkReadStoragePermission(final Context context){
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        if(currentAPIVersion>= 23)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Storage Permission Necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


   public static boolean checkWriteStoragePermission(final Context context){
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        if(currentAPIVersion>= 23)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Storage Permission Necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```